# Google Apps Script: work with multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with some information about users here an example:

Name, Time, Location
Peter,15.01.15, Frankfurt
Michael, 18.02.15, Frankfurt
Peter,17.02.15, Paris
Michael, 17.02.15, Paris

What i would like is to create for each unique user a new sheet and sort the new sheet. Is that possible with GAS? It should look like this:

/*New Sheet*/
Name, Time, Location
Peter,15.01.15, Frankfurt
Peter,17.02.15, Paris
/*New Sheet*/
Name, Time, Location
Michael, 17.02.15, Paris
Michael, 18.02.15, Frankfurt

Thanks.
EDIT:

```
  function getall(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), 
  sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source'),
  newSheet = ss.insertSheet('newSheet'),
  sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange(),
  sourceRows = sourceRange.getValues();
  newSheet.appendRow(sourceRows[0]);
  var   i;
  for (i = 1; i < sourceRows.length; i += 1) {

  newSheet.appendRow(sourceRows[i]);

  } 

  Browser.msgBox("New Sheet Added!");
  }
```

Edit 2:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), 
  sourceRange = ss.getDataRange(),
  sourceRows = sourceRange.getValues();

  var users = {},
  colWithTheUsersNames = 6,
  currSheet;

  for( var lin = 1; lin < sourceRows.length; lin++ ){
  if( !users[ sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ] ) sourceRows[lin]     [colWithTheUsersNames] = [];

  users[ sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ].push( sourceRows[lin]  [colWithTheUsersNames] );
  }

 for( var usr in users ){
 currSheet = ss.insertSheet( usr );
 currSheet.getRange(1,1, users[usr].length, users[usr][0].length  ).setValues(users[usr]);
 }
```

Edit 3:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), 
  sourceRange = ss.getDataRange(),
  sourceRows = sourceRange.getValues(), 
  users = {},
  colWithTheUsersNames = 6,
  currSheet;

for( var lin = 1; lin < sourceRows.length; lin++ ){

if( users[ sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ] ) sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] = [];
    for(var column = 0; column < sourceRows.length; column++){
      if("undefined" != typeof users[sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames]]) {
          if("undefined" != typeof sourceRows[lin][column]){
        users[sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ].push(sourceRows[lin][column]);
          }
      }
      else {
        users[sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ] = new Array();
        if("undefined" != typeof sourceRows[lin][column]){
        users[sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ].push(sourceRows[lin][column]);
        }
      }
    }

}
//   users[ sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ].push( sourceRows[lin][column]);

var i = 0;
for( var usr in users ){
  currSheet = ss.insertSheet( usr );
  Logger.log(typeof users[usr]);
  currSheet.getRange(1,1, users[usr].length, users[usr].length ).setValues(users[usr]);
}
```

Edit 4:

```
function getallEmployer(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), 
  sourceRange = ss.getDataRange(),
  sourceValue = sourceRange.getValues(),
  sourceRows = sourceRange.getNumRows(),
  users = {},
  colWithTheUsersNames = 7,
  currSheet;

for( var lin = 1; lin < sourceRows; lin++ ){

if( users[ !sourceValue[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ] ) sourceValue[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] = [];
  //for(var column = 0; column < sourceValue[lin].getNumColumns; column++){
      if("undefined" != typeof users[sourceValue[lin][colWithTheUsersNames]]) {
          if("undefined" != typeof sourceValue[lin]){
        users[sourceValue[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ].push(sourceValue[lin]);
          }
      }
      else {
        users[sourceValue[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ] = new Array();
        if("undefined" != typeof sourceValue[lin]){
        users[sourceValue[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ].push(sourceValue[lin]);
        }
     // }
    }

}
//   users[ sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ].push( sourceRows[lin][column]);

var i = 0;
for( var usr in users ){
  currSheet = ss.insertSheet( usr );
  var range = currSheet.getRange("A1:D1");
  var parameters = [["Date","Name","Project Category", "Time","Nicht verrechenbar","Bemerkung"]];
  range.setValues(parameters);
  Logger.log(typeof users[usr]);
  currSheet.getRange(2,1, users[usr].length, users[usr][0].length ).setValues(users[usr]);
}

}
```

Comment: Yes, it is very possible, what have you tried so far?

Comment: See Edit. Sorry this is the first time i use GAS,

Comment: Why the extra spaces? Why does it end with `curr`? There's 2 flaws to the script, but the methods are correct, it isn't correctly initalizing a the new user array, it is pushing a single value in the user array when it should be pushing the whole line array. You could overcome this just by debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, creates a new sheet for every user, and append alls rows of that user to thy sheet:

```
var users = {},
    colWithTheUsersNames = ??,
    currSheet;

for( var lin = 0; lin < sourceRows.length; lin++ ){
   if( !users[ sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ] ) sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] = [];

   users[ sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] ].push( sourceRows[lin][colWithTheUsersNames] );
}

for( var usr in users ){
   currSheet = ss.insertSheet( usr );

   currSheet.getRange(1,1, users[usr].length, users[usr][0].length ).setValues(users[usr]);
}
```

Not tested but should work.

Now only need to implement verification for sheets already present and such.

Comment: @Taaut See my comment in the original answer, it's easily fixable, I didn't corrected it so you can see it next time and find a way to do it simple debugging by yourself, and later edit my answer to the correct code.

Comment: See edit 3. Everything works but the setvaules had an error. Cant Array to object[][].

Comment: @Taaut You're selecting the same number of rows and columns here `users[usr].length, users[usr].length`, the second value should have select the first row of the user with `[0]` just as in my example. But that error occurs when the array is not perfectly formatted, it must be a Double Array, in which each Row must have the same number of Columns, and all indexes must be initialized with at least a blank value `""`.

Comment: So the Edit 4 works for me now...xD Thanks. So now i need to find out how to sort this automatic and only setvalues that need...again thanks.